# How to solve infinite sums of square roots which converge to specific values

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Is this limit possible to solve?

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{a=1}^{n}\sum_{b=1}^{n}\sum_{c=1}^{n}\sum_{d=1}^{n}\sqrt{\left(a-b\right)^{2}+\left(c-d\right)^{2}}}{n^{5}-n^{3}} $$

I got here in an attempt to solve "1 by 1 square; two random points within; average distance of points" without college-level calculus or probability theory.

I know that the solution is $\frac{2+\sqrt{2}+5\ln\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)}{15}$ or around 0.521, which the expression above approaches.  I am solely unsure if it is possible to prove this, and would like to learn about solving limits such as this.

Comment: In general, if you are not allowed to use calculus or technique beyond to evaluates a sum, there won't be too much tools remain you can use. The only tools I can think of are geometric series and/or rewrite a sum as a telescoping one. Since your sum has a lot of square roots, they won't  work. In fact, it is easier to compute the underlying integral directly than evaluate the sum and find the limit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just for your curiosity.*

As @achille hui commented, the only way is to compute the integrals; they are not very difficult, each of them leading to logarithms.

Skipping all intermediate steps, the numerator (replacing the $\sum_{k=1}^n$ by $\int_{k=1}^n$ and replacing logarithms by inverse hyperbolic functions) is just
$$\frac{2+\sqrt{2}+5 \sinh ^{-1}(1)}{15} (n-1)^5 $$ which makes for the whole expression
$$\frac{2+\sqrt{2}+5 \sinh ^{-1}(1)}{15}\,\,\, \frac{(n-1)^4}{n^3 (n+1)}$$

$$\frac{(n-1)^4}{n^3 (n+1)}=1-\frac{5}{n}+\frac{11}{n^2}-\frac{15}{n^3}+\frac{16}{n^3(n+1)}$$ Then the limit (the same as your).